# For Bernoulli ODE $y^\prime+a(x)y=b(x)y^n$, why $a$ and $b$ are continuous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Bernoulli ODE: $y^\prime+a(x)y=b(x)y^n$

Why we need continuity of $a$ and $b$ on the interval we are working on?

Comment: To be pedantic, you're wondering why we require $a$ and $b$ are continuous.  $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are just numbers.

Comment: That is exactly what i m wondering

Comment: @Aweygan,are $a(x)$,$b(x)$  numbers?

Comment: @haqnatural Presumably.  Unless andii is asking about a family of Bernoulli ODEs

Comment: When functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are continues, the existence and uniqueness theorem ensures that one solution exactly exist.